Model Training for Segmentation
I want to train and evaluate models to find the best models for my segments, but sklearn is having something go wrong with the tags and the estimators, and I can't figure out the issue. There might be something wrong with the tags.py, base.py, and search.py scripts, but I'm not certain of that either.
# Import libraries
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split, GridSearchCV, KFold
from xgboost import XGBRegressor
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score, precision_score, recall_score, f1_score, roc_auc_score
import joblib

# Develop function to train and evaluate models
def train_and_evaluate_models(input_train_csv, models_dir, metrics_output_csv):
    # Load the training data
    train_data = pd.read_csv(input_train_csv)

    # Extract features and target
    X_train = train_data.drop(columns=['Response_ID', 'segment'])
    y_train = train_data['segment']

    metrics_list = []

    # Define hyperparameters to tune
    param_grid = {
        'max_depth': [3, 5, 7],
        'n_estimators': [100, 200, 300],
        'learning_rate': [0.01, 0.1, 0.2],
        'subsample': [0.8, 1.0],
        'colsample_bytree': [0.8, 1.0]
    }

    # Train, save models, and evaluate for each segment
    for segment in range(1, 7):
        # Binary target for the current segment
        y_train_segment = (y_train == segment).astype(int)

        # Split the data for evaluation
        X_train_split, X_valid, y_train_split, y_valid = train_test_split(X_train, y_train_segment, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)

        # Initialize the model
        model = XGBRegressor(
            objective='binary:logistic',
            eval_metric='logloss',
            use_label_encoder=False,
            early_stopping_rounds=10
        )

        # Hyperparameter tuning using GridSearchCV
        kf = KFold(n_splits=3, shuffle=True, random_state=42)
        grid_search = GridSearchCV(estimator=model, param_grid=param_grid, cv=kf, scoring='roc_auc', verbose=1, n_jobs=-1)

        # Fit the model with early stopping
        grid_search.fit(X_train_split, y_train_split, 
                        eval_set=[(X_valid, y_valid)], 
                        verbose=False)

        # Get the best model from grid search
        best_model = grid_search.best_estimator_

        # Save the best model to disk
        model_filename = f'{models_dir}/segment_{segment}_model.joblib'
        joblib.dump(best_model, model_filename)
        print(f'Model for segment {segment} saved to {model_filename}')

        # Predict on validation set
        y_valid_pred = best_model.predict(X_valid)
        y_valid_pred_binary = [1 if prob > 0.5 else 0 for prob in y_valid_pred]

        # Calculate evaluation metrics
        accuracy = accuracy_score(y_valid, y_valid_pred_binary)
        precision = precision_score(y_valid, y_valid_pred_binary)
        recall = recall_score(y_valid, y_valid_pred_binary)
        f1 = f1_score(y_valid, y_valid_pred_binary)
        auc = roc_auc_score(y_valid, y_valid_pred)

        metrics_list.append({
            'Segment': segment,
            'Accuracy': accuracy,
            'Precision': precision,
            'Recall': recall,
            'F1 Score': f1,
            'AUC': auc
        })

    # Save the metrics to a CSV file
    metrics_df = pd.DataFrame(metrics_list)
    metrics_df.to_csv(metrics_output_csv, index=False)

    return metrics_df

# Pathways
input_train_csv = r"C:\\Users\\me\\input.csv"
models_dir = r"C:\\Users\\me"
metrics_output_csv = r"C:\\Users\\me\\output.csv"

# Train, evaluate, and save models
metrics_df = train_and_evaluate_models(input_train_csv, models_dir, metrics_output_csv)
print(metrics_df)

I've tried upgrading xgboost, and downgrading sklearn, in order to address the compatibility issues, but the same error kept popping up. I've also tried multiple workarounds for the compatibility, along with making sure that the script is reading the inputs as a float or int, and not a string, but that hasn't worked either, resulting in the same errors.
C:\ProgramData\spyder-6\envs\spyder-runtime\Lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\_tags.py:354: FutureWarning: The XGBRegressor or classes from which it inherits use `_get_tags` and `_more_tags`. Please define the `__sklearn_tags__` method, or inherit from `sklearn.base.BaseEstimator` and/or other appropriate mixins such as `sklearn.base.TransformerMixin`, `sklearn.base.ClassifierMixin`, `sklearn.base.RegressorMixin`, and `sklearn.base.OutlierMixin`. From scikit-learn 1.7, not defining `__sklearn_tags__` will raise an error.
  warnings.warn(
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
File C:\ProgramData\spyder-6\envs\spyder-runtime\Lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\utils.py:209, in exec_encapsulate_locals(code_ast, globals, locals, exec_fun, filename)
    207     if filename is None:
    208         filename = "<stdin>"
--> 209     exec_fun(compile(code_ast, filename, "exec"), globals, None)
    210 finally:
    211     if use_locals_hack:
    212         # Cleanup code

File c:\users\me\pyhton programs\2-model training\2_model_training.py:93
     90 metrics_output_csv = r"C:\\Users\\me\\model_metrics.csv"
     92 # Train, evaluate, and save models
---> 93 metrics_df = train_and_evaluate_models(input_train_csv, models_dir, metrics_output_csv)
     94 print(metrics_df)

File c:\users\me\pyhton programs\2-model training\2_model_training.py:49, in train_and_evaluate_models(input_train_csv, models_dir, metrics_output_csv)
     46 grid_search = GridSearchCV(estimator=model, param_grid=param_grid, cv=kf, scoring='roc_auc', verbose=1, n_jobs=-1)
     48 # Fit the model with early stopping
---> 49 grid_search.fit(X_train_split, y_train_split, 
     50                 eval_set=[(X_valid, y_valid)], 
     51                 verbose=False)
     53 # Get the best model from grid search
     54 best_model = grid_search.best_estimator_

File C:\ProgramData\spyder-6\envs\spyder-runtime\Lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py:1389, in _fit_context.<locals>.decorator.<locals>.wrapper(estimator, *args, **kwargs)
   1382     estimator._validate_params()
   1384 with config_context(
   1385     skip_parameter_validation=(
   1386         prefer_skip_nested_validation or global_skip_validation
   1387     )
   1388 ):
-> 1389     return fit_method(estimator, *args, **kwargs)

File C:\ProgramData\spyder-6\envs\spyder-runtime\Lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_search.py:932, in BaseSearchCV.fit(self, X, y, **params)
    928 params = _check_method_params(X, params=params)
    930 routed_params = self._get_routed_params_for_fit(params)
--> 932 cv_orig = check_cv(self.cv, y, classifier=is_classifier(estimator))
    933 n_splits = cv_orig.get_n_splits(X, y, **routed_params.splitter.split)
    935 base_estimator = clone(self.estimator)

File C:\ProgramData\spyder-6\envs\spyder-runtime\Lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py:1237, in is_classifier(estimator)
   1230     warnings.warn(
   1231         f"passing a class to {print(inspect.stack()[0][3])} is deprecated and "
   1232         "will be removed in 1.8. Use an instance of the class instead.",
   1233         FutureWarning,
   1234     )
   1235     return getattr(estimator, "_estimator_type", None) == "classifier"
-> 1237 return get_tags(estimator).estimator_type == "classifier"

File C:\ProgramData\spyder-6\envs\spyder-runtime\Lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\_tags.py:405, in get_tags(estimator)
    403 for klass in reversed(type(estimator).mro()):
    404     if "__sklearn_tags__" in vars(klass):
--> 405         sklearn_tags_provider[klass] = klass.__sklearn_tags__(estimator)  # type: ignore[attr-defined]
    406         class_order.append(klass)
    407     elif "_more_tags" in vars(klass):

File C:\ProgramData\spyder-6\envs\spyder-runtime\Lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py:613, in RegressorMixin.__sklearn_tags__(self)
    612 def __sklearn_tags__(self):
--> 613     tags = super().__sklearn_tags__()
    614     tags.estimator_type = "regressor"
    615     tags.regressor_tags = RegressorTags()

AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute '__sklearn_tags__'


Which version of scikit-learn are you running?

You are using a Regressor model for a Classification problem.

@SergedeGossondeVarennes, I'm using the most recent version. I did downgrade it to a compatible version (1.2.2), but I still ran across the same issues.

@rehaqds, That's a good point, I'll go ahead and give it a shot. Thank you.

This question is similar to: 'super' object has no attribute '__sklearn_tags__'. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
