'super' object has no attribute '__sklearn_tags__'
I am encountering an AttributeError while fitting an XGBRegressor using RandomizedSearchCV from Scikit-learn. The error message states:
'super' object has no attribute '__sklearn_tags__'.

This occurs when I invoke the fit method on the RandomizedSearchCV object. I suspect it could be related to compatibility issues between Scikit-learn and XGBoost or Python version. I am using Python 3.12, and both Scikit-learn and XGBoost are installed with their latest versions.
I attempted to tune the hyperparameters of an XGBRegressor using RandomizedSearchCV from Scikit-learn. I expected the model to fit the training data without issues and provide the best parameters after cross-validation.
I also checked for compatibility issues, ensured the libraries were up-to-date, and reinstalled Scikit-learn and XGBoost, but the error persists.

related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79289735/model-training-for-segmentation

Scikit-learn version 1.6 modified the API around its "tags", and that's the cause of this error.  XGBoost has made the necessary changes in PR11021, but at present that hasn't made it into a released version.  You can either keep your sklearn version <1.6, or build XGBoost directly from github (or upgrade XGBoost, after a new version is released).

thanks for this ,the downgraded 1.5.2 is working

I also had a similiar error,Xg boost too. But what the guy above me said, uninstall and reinstalling a lower version of sklearn (i used version 1.5.2) fixed this issue for me!
!pip uninstall -y scikit-learn
!pip install scikit-learn==1.5.2


yes,got it followed the same

Version 1.5.2 does not solve the problem. Try downgrading further. What worked for me was 1.3.1.
